# sum function with Distinct

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am working on one PL/SQL procedure where I need your inputs. Below query is running inside a loop and loop is running for 16 times(just an example). ideally the count should be 16 but v_cnt is giving me '1' for 16 times however I want the query should sum up and give 16 as a output.

```
    select  (count (distinct (ies.shipment_gid)) )into v_cnt from  ie_shipmentstatus ies , 
    shipment_stop 
    ss
    where ies.shipment_gid = ss.shipment_gid
    and ss.stop_num = c
    and ss.stop_type = 'P'
    and ies.shipment_gid = 'I/A.021-TSO-S1993596'
    and ies.status_code_gid = 'I.24-1';
```

I have tried to sum function but it is not working for me.

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's _set quantifier_. Simply write `count(distinct ies.shipment_gid)` to make code clearer.

Comment: ok, any idea on how to sum up loop values

Comment: Don't run the query in a loop.  Run the query once on all the data.  Without seeing what the loop looks like, it is rather hard to be more specific.  Running the exact same query 16 times seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Is `c` the loop variable?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this query won't "sum" nor return "16". If you're doing it in a loop, then create your own counter:

```
declare
  l_cnt number := 0;
begin
  for i in 1 .. 16 loop
    select whatever
    into something_else
    from  ie_shipmentstatus ies , 
    shipment_stop 
    ss
    where ies.shipment_gid = ss.shipment_gid
    and ss.stop_num = c
    and ss.stop_type = 'P'
    and ies.shipment_gid = 'I/A.021-TSO-S1993596'
    and ies.status_code_gid = 'I.24-1';

    l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_cnt);      --> this would now return 16
end;
```